# NIO Connector in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm trying to enable NIO Connector in Tomcat 6.0 by configuring server.xml file, but I'm getting **Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8081.** in the browser whenever I type **localhost:8081**.

This is how I've configured NIO connector in Tomcat 6.0. May I know what's the problem?

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="org.apache.
coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Comment: What does the server startup logs say?

Answer (score 21):

I've tried your tag on my server.

Your Connector tag has one unnecessary space between `apache.` and `coyote`
Remove it or try with the one below.

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

It should start up.