# How to configure Tomcat to support primefaces-push (atmosphere)

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7, liferay-6, atmosphere

I'm working with liferay 6.2 (Tomcat 7) and Primefaces 5.0.
I tryed to execute [the counter example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/counter.xhtml) but not worked. More precisely, I downloaded the showcase 5.0 war from primefaces site.

I read that I have to enable NIO Connector. So, according [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996761/nio-connector-in-tomcat), I added the connector:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

But primefaces push still doesn't work.

What I have to enable in Tomcat in order to make work primefaces push?

Comment: Follow this tutorial if it helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISacZWgcWxo

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the undocumented specification or it is a bug, but the @PushEndpoint class needs @OnOpen and @OnClose function, even if they are empty.

Add these lines to the @PushEndpoint annotated class:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen( RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus e ) {
}

@OnClose
public void onClose( RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus e ) {
}
```

For me this was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me brother with Prifaces 5, Tomcat 7 and import atmosphere-runtime-2.2.3.jar
without any configuration in web.xml

```
<h:form>
 <p:socket onMessage="bien" channel="/messageDetail" />
</h:form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function bien(data) {
    alert("boneo");
    //$('.display').html(data);
}
</script>
```